# How to center crop an image in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, image, swiftui, center, crop

I'm new to SwiftUI. I guess everyone is at this point. I've been an app developer for about 6 years now and I feel stupid asking this question on StackOverflow. But I looked everywhere. How do I center crop an image in an ImageView in SwiftUI?

I know there's an option to change the aspect ratio but I only see fit and fill. I just want the imageView to centerCrop(android term) the image. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Android's [`ImageView.ScaleType` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) describes `CENTER_CROP` as:

> CENTER_CROP
>
> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
> both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
> larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).
> The image is then centered in the view.

This is essentially what *Aspect Fill Scaling* (aka `.scaledToFill()`) does, except (surprisingly) *Aspect Fill* doesn't clip the parts that fall outside of the frame.

By making the image `.resizable`, and applying `.scaledToFill()`. the image will be scaled proportionally to fill its available frame leaving off the top and bottom or sides as necessary.  `.clipped()` then removes the parts of the image outside of the frame.

```
Image("myImage")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
    .clipped()
```

To make this more convenient, I created this `extension` of `Image`:

```
extension Image {
    func centerCropped() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            self
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

To use the `Image` `extension`, just put it in a file in your project (a name like `image-centercropped.swift` will work nicely).  Then just add `.centerCropped()` to any image you want to be center cropped.

```
Image("apolloimage").centerCropped()
```

It uses `GeometryReader` to figure out its frame so that it can crop the image correctly, which means *you* don't have to specify the frame to get proper clipping.  You are free to size the image however you like using an explicit frame, or by just adding `padding()` and `Spacer()` to keep it nicely placed relative to other user interface items.

For example:  If you want an image to fill the screen of the phone:

```
struct ContentView: View { 
    var body: some View {
        Image("apolloimage")
            .centerCropped()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

will nicely show the center of the image by scaling the image to show either the full height or the full width of the image and cropping the parts the hang over on the other dimension.

---

### Demonstration:

Here's a demo that shows how the image is centered and cropped as the image grows.  In this demo, the frame width is a constant `360` while the frame height varies from `50` to `700` as the slider advances to the right.  At the beginning when the frame is short, the tops and bottoms of the image are cropped.  As the frame exceeds the aspectRatio of the original image, the resulting image is centered but cropped on the left and right sides.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var frameheight: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Spacer()
            Image("apolloimage")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 360, height: self.frameheight)
                .clipped()
            Spacer()
            Slider(value: self.$frameheight, in: 50...700)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

or an equivalent test using `.centerCropped()`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var frameheight: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Spacer()
            Image("apolloimage")
                .centerCropped()
                .frame(width: 360, height: self.frameheight)
            Spacer()
            Slider(value: self.$frameheight, in: 50...700)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Demo running on the simulator of .centerCropped scaling]

---

### Alternate Solution

Another way to make a center cropped image is to make the image an `.overlay()` of `Color.clear`.  This allows `Color.clear` to establish the clipping bounds.

```
Color.clear
.overlay(
    Image("apolloimage")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
)
.clipped()
```

and the corresponding `extension` to `Image` looks like this:

```
extension Image {
    func centerCropped() -> some View {
        Color.clear
        .overlay(
            self
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
        )
        .clipped()
    }
}
```

Comment: @vacawama I would've marked this as the correct answer if you didn't use a frame. I don't want to add specific frame values (height or width). I want the image to resize itself based on the screen size.

Comment: Look again.  Use the `Image` `extension` that I provided.  You don't have to specify the frame.  Just use `Image("imageName").centerCropped()`.  I even show you how to have it fill the screen of the phone, also without specifying the frame.

Comment: To use the `Image` `extension`, just drop it into a file in your project.  Call it "image-centercropped.swift".  Then just add `.centerCropped()` to any image you want to be center cropped.  There is no need to specify the frame.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to crop the square centre of image for view like iPhone Photo app.

```
extension Image {
    func centerSquareCropped() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let length = geo.size.width > geo.size.height ? geo.size.height : geo.size.width
            self
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: length, height: length, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was originally using @vacawama's answer for this which uses the `GeometryReader` but discovered that actually this isn't necessary.

(I'm writing this with Xcode 13 and running in iOS15 if that makes any difference?)

Using this is sufficient...

```
Image(uiImage: image) // insert your own image here :D
  .resizable()
  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
  .clipped()
```

I'm using this as the `label` parameter of a `Button` inside a `List` so the whole thing is like...

```
Section("Photo") {
  Button {
    // the action
  } label: {
    if let image = viewStore.imagePickerState.image {
      Image(uiImage: image)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .clipped()
    } else {
      PersonAvatarButton()
    }
  }
}
.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
.listRowBackground(Color.gray)
.listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
```

I haven't defined the frame anywhere for this, just the aspect ratio of the `Section`.

What I end up with is a square button with rounded corners and the photo all the way to the edge. Resized to fill but not squashed in any way. And the button size is determined by the screen size.

So I don't have any concrete sizes in my code.

Comment: This had me thinking it worked just as nicely as the GeometryReader answer, but turns out that your method doesn't actually center the image.