# How do I setup ZStack with Image filled to the widget bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My code looks like this:

```
    ZStack {
        
        NetworkImage(url: url)
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 5) {
            Spacer()
            Text("this is my quite long title here")
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            Text("subtitle this is my long long subtitle to create multiply lines")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        }
        .padding()
    }

struct NetworkImage: View {
    let url: URL?
    var body: some View {
        if let url = url, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
    }
}
```

But this looks bad and it is not what I need t achieve.

I need to make it aligned to the right and to the bottom with some padding from the edges. That is all. How can I do this?

[image]
[image]

After update from @user1046037 answer it looks like:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code Changes:

### 1. ZStack Alignment

```
ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .trailing, vertical: .bottom)) {
```

### 2. Crop in the center

In `NetworkImage`, center crop (code provided) in the image extension.

Thanks to @vacawama
[How to center crop an image in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651077/how-to-center-crop-an-image-in-swiftui)

## Complete Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .trailing, vertical: .bottom)) {
            
            NetworkImage(url: URL(string: "https://unsplash.com/photos/KZv3Rb_OIXI/download?force=true"))
            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 5) {
                Spacer()
                Text("this is my quite long title here")
                        .font(.title)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .lineLimit(nil)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                Text("subtitle this is my long long subtitle to create multiply lines")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .lineLimit(nil)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

//Center Crop
extension Image {
    func centerCropped() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            self
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}

struct NetworkImage: View {
    let url: URL?
    var body: some View {
        if let url = url, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                .centerCropped()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesnt work... Still the same. It looks like the image view moves trailing out of widget bounds.

Comment: In the NetworkImage, could you use `.scaledToFit()` instead of `.scaledToFill()` along with the above mentioned change?

Comment: Updated my answer, just to ensure we are on the same page, I am previewing not on the widget, but this was with a landscape picture

Comment: I updated the question, but this is not what I need, because an image doesnt fill the whole space...

Comment: See the updated by cropping in the center, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651077/how-to-center-crop-an-image-in-swiftui

Answer (score 3):

The `ZStack` with the `Image` in it is the problem. The ZStack isn’t *cropping* the Image, it’s actually *growing to fit the image* and extending outside the bounds of the widget. The Text is inside that same ZStack, so it too grows to fill the available space.

Maybe this helps visualize the issue (black round-rect is the **widget** frame):
[image: widget content with black frame showing where its cropped]

#### Solution

Put the image in the VStack's `.background` instead:

```swift
var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 5) {
        Spacer()
        Text("this is my quite long title here")
            .font(.title)
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        Text("subtitle this is my long long subtitle to create multiply lines")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(NetworkImage(url: url))

}

struct NetworkImage: View {
    let url: URL?
    var body: some View {
        if let url = url, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the image fits to the view. Doesnt fill a whole space... Is there anything to set contentMode like `.aspectFill` instead of `.aspectFit`

Comment: Are you using the `NetworkImage` from your original post, with the `scaledToFill`? (I updated my answer to clarify what NetworkImage is)